# JavaScript в bootstrap

Tags: php, ajax, bootstrap

Использую bootstrap в проекте. Есть страница с меню и блоком в который через ajax подгружается контент. Проблема в том, что в страницах, загруженых через ajax не хочет работать(или странно работает) js bootstrap. В данном случае модальное окно. На основной страницы создается без проблем, а на подгруженых создается и сразу исчезает и то через раз.
 В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Все дело в том что выполняющийся с момента инициализации `javascript` и `jQuery` в частности, ничего не знает о только что добавленных в `dom-дерево` элементах.
Вам нужно переинициализировать плагины уже после добавления элементов.

Comment: Переинициализировать это заново подключить? Если да, то не помогло

Comment: я не знаю конкретно Вашего случая, но у Вас должно быть что-то вроде этого ( строчка взята из хелпа ) - `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`. Видите как `jQ` просят выбрать все элементы с классом `'.dropdown-toggle` и инициализировать их. Примерно так же должно быть и у Вас. Это если причина реально в этом, но это первое что приходит в голову.

Comment: Проблема решается, если для вызова использовать $('#myModal').modal('show');

Comment: Так в этом случае и происходит переинициализация.